# How to convert json string to a matrix for training using matlab?

Tags: json, matlab, matrix

I have Json data and i want to use it in classification.

data sample:

```
{"reviewerID": "AKM1MP6P0OYPR", "asin": "0132793040", "reviewerName": "Vicki  Gibson \"momo4\"", "helpful": [1, 1], "reviewText": "Corey Barker does a great job of explaining Blend Modes in this DVD. All of the Kelby training videos are great but pricey to buy individually. If you really want bang for your buck just subscribe to Kelby Training online.", "overall": 5.0, "summary": "Very thorough", "unixReviewTime": 1365811200, "reviewTime": "04 13, 2013"}
```

I'm supposed to use it in trainng, but I don't know how to deal with it. I'm used to types of data like iris dataset (matrices).

like this:

```
data =

5.1000    3.5000    1.4000    0.2000
4.9000    3.0000    1.4000    0.2000
4.7000    3.2000    1.3000    0.2000
4.6000    3.1000    1.5000    0.2000
```

What do i need to Make it like this form? by this form, i mean matrix i don't mean numbers.

I tried to parse the json string and i got this result:

```
data = 

Columns 1 through 5

[1x1 struct]    [1x1 struct]    [1x1 struct]    [1x1 struct]    [1x1 struct]

 Columns 6 through 9

[1x1 struct]    [1x1 struct]    [1x1 struct]    [1x1 struct]
```

Comment: What form does it need to be in? How did you attempt to parse the string?

Comment: i need it in a matrix form. I used a function to built from scratch to parse it.

Comment: 'matrix form' is meaningless here, your data is not homogenous. Please provide the *exact* output you need from the input string and what you have tried.

Comment: I'm only interested in this ` "reviewText": "Corey Barker does a great job of explaining Blend Modes in this DVD. All of the Kelby training videos are great but pricey to buy individually. If you really want bang for your buck just subscribe to Kelby Training online." `

Comment: @user3054453 There's a nice summary on [UndocumentedMatlab](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/json-matlab-integration) on how to work with JSON strings. There's also [kyamagu's version](https://github.com/kyamagu/matlab-json).